# What is the driver name when setting ComboPooledDataSource driver for Couchbase?

Tags: java, jdbc, couchbase

What is the driver name when setting `ComboPooledDataSource` driver for Couchbase?

```
String driver = "Couchbase driver name";
ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
dataSource.setDriverClass(driver);
```

I'm using this dependency:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.couchbase.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Check the documentation of your Couchbase JDBC driver for its driver classname.

Comment: Are you using the CDATA JDBC driver?

Comment: I edited my question and add the maven dependancy that i use.